# Xarray's idxmax function returns an error when trying to assign the variable id corresponding with maximum pixel value across raster stack

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have an xarray dataarray with dimensions time, lat and lon. The time dimension represents periods of n days, e.g. 5 days, 10 days, 15 days etc. I am trying to create a new raster with pixel values equal to the variable id along the time dimension (n days) for the maximum pixel value within the data array stack.

I'm using the code:

```
corrs_da.idxmax(dim='time',skipna=True,fill_value=None)
```

And I get the error: `KeyError: 'Dimension "time" does not have coordinates'`

Here is an example of the input dataarray:

[image: data array example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you need to run

`corrs_da = corrs_da.rename({"variable": "time"})`

before doing `corrs_da.idxmax(dim='time',skipna=True,fill_value=None)`.

Not completely sure why though, since `corrs_da.time.coords` does seem to indicate that time has coordinates.

Comment: Thank you Bert! That works perfectly. The final formula I used after applying 'rename' was corrs_da.idxmax(dim='time',skipna=True)